# Bug in comment link not appearing for trusted users and moderators

Tags: support, comments, notifications, migrated-questions, locked-questions

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110637), which was migrated from Writers.SE to ELU, is missing its comment link.

[image]

The posting is not locked (on ELU, the way it now is due to migration back on Writers), and neither trusted users nor moderators can see a comment link. One of our moderation closed it and then went to leave a comment, but was unable to do so.

What’s going on here?  Isn’t this a bug?

Comment: Oh, but it *is* locked. See the greyed out edit link? Dead giveaway...

Comment: @animuson Permit me to rephrase: it does not say it is locked, as the notification has been lost. Also, a moderator can edit a locked post, so gets no such notification; a moderator also may need to be add a comment to post; must they really unlock it first?

Comment: Yes, they must. The point of the lock is to prevent two versions of a question in two different places. When a migration gets rejected, it gets locked on the target site and unlocked on the origin site.

Comment: @animuson I am not disagreeing with the locking strategy. I am saying that locked posts are supposed to say that they are locked, and this one did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a migrated question that was closed on EL&U, which rejects the migration and locks the post. If there are more than two notices on a post, only the first two are shown. This causes the locked notice to be absent in this case.

Moderators can just unlock the post and then they can comment again.

This is not really a bug, but a rather confusing interaction of those features. I'm also not exactly sure why rejected migrations have to be locked, to be honest. It would get confusing if the post was reopened, but silently locking seems to be the worse choice to me.

Comment: Surely they are not supposed to be locked against moderators, too, should they? Sometimes a moderator needs to add a comment.

Comment: @tchrist Moderators are also affected by locks, but they can just unlock the post if they need to comment.

Comment: @tchrist You can see that it's locked here: http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/110637/revisions

Comment: @Seth Sure, but is that a substitute for the normal banner? Where did that go?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think Community sets one.  Simple as that.

Comment: That would make a good feature request...

Comment: @tchrist Only two banners are shown at maximum, that is the reason why no locked banner is visible

Comment: I’m selecting your answer because I agree with your analysis that this is a rather confusing interaction of features, and that silently locking the post seems a worse choice than non-silently locking it.  Strangely, if I bring up the question, my title bar claims that I am in the process of editing that very question, which certainly is incorrect; this is reproducible on multiple browsers, and smells like a related but separate bug.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't leave comments on locked posts. Ask a moderator, they can unlock it (the option is in the "mod" menu), leave the comment, and relock it.

Whenever a migration is rejected, the post is locked on the rejecting site.

Comment: It would have been more obvious if it actually bothered to say it has been locked; that notification was lost.

Comment: Actually, it does get unlocked on the origin site. ;P

Comment: @tchrist: Yeah, that's a quirk with rejected migrations. Technically, if you reject a migration you're not supposed to modify the post anyway, you should modify it (edits, comments, etc) on the other side.